# JSF ViewState errors using JMeter

Tags: jsf, jmeter, performance-testing, viewstate

Using `JMeter` I need to extract the JSF view state value. I am able to extract the value.

Below is the viewstate form response:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="j_id4" />
```

My Regular expression extractor is as below:

```
<input\s+type="hidden"\s+name="javax\.faces\.ViewState"\s+id="javax\.faces\.ViewState"\s+value="([^"]+)".*/>
```

This works fine. I get `j_id4` value correctly and places.

But my big problem is for every API call the value changes. First API call the view state value is `j_id4`, but the next API call view state will be `j_id5`

How do I handle this?

Comment: Can you share the response and the regular expression extractor, also are the JSF view state values continue to increment by 1 through all the api calls?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Parsing HTML with Regular Expressions is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I would recommend going for [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead, the relevant configuration would be as simple as:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `viewstate`
   - CSS/JQuery expression: `input[name=javax.faces.ViewState]`
   - Attribute: `value`
2. If your test assumes 2 (or more) [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers you will need to either apply a CSS/JQuery Extractor to **each** of them as [ViewState](https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/jsf-viewstate-and-csrf-hacker-attacks/) will change on each call so you will need to extract it each time. Alternatively you can put CSS/JQuery Extractor at the same level as your HTTP Request samplers, JMeter's Post-Processors are obeying [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so single Extractor will be applied to all the Samplers it its scope. Something like:

   [image: JMeter CSS JQuery Extractor]

Answer (score 0):

You can add 2 regular expression extractors, one will extract **j_id**, the expression will be as below:

- Regular expression: **value="(.*?)\d"**

The second will extract the number **4**, the expression will be as below:

- Regular expression: **value=".+(\d)"**

Now add a beanshell post processor for each of your API's with the following code:

```
String j_id = vars.get("j_id");// j_id is the reference name of the first regular expression extractor
int num = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("num"));// num is the reference name for the second regular expression extractor
num = num + 1;
vars.put("num",String.valueOf(num));
vars.put("JSF", j_id + num);
```

For the first API you can use the same regular expression you were using, after adding the above beanshell post processor to all of the API's that you need to extract the JSF view state value from, use ${JSf} which will hold the value **j_id5** for the second API and **j_id6** for the third API and so on.